# Sharing data between two applications on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, node.js

I have two processes running on Linux, one is NodeJs application and other is a C++ application. NodeJs application receives data from server which is also a NodeJS application, now this data is to be used by C++ application.

For now i am writing data in a text file from NodeJs application and then reading it from C++ application. But this is slow, also it cause problems as file can be written asynchronously.

My question is what is the best way to share the data between these two applications keeping in mind that data can be received asynchronously?

Comment: There are many ways to do [*inter-process communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), and files is only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Create REST API for C++ application in NodeJS. (c++ client: https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp).

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
   var dataObjectToSendHere = 'here';
   res.json(dataObjectToSendHere);
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you a little more, what you need are *two* things: To send data from one application to another (what you use files for now), and to asynchronously signal one process from another (to tell it that data is available).

You *can* do this with files actually, but instead of using only a single file you use multiple files, one each time there is new data. Write them in a special directory that the other process monitors for changes, and when it detects a new file it simply reads that file and then deletes it.

Another way is to have a more direct connection, either through named pipes or sockets (local (i.e. `AF_LOCAL`) or "normal"). Then invent a simple protocol on top of either TCP or UDP that can handle both the signaling and bulk data transfer.

And of course since one application is a node.js app, you could simply use a REST-like interface, and have the other program poll for new data. For this you don't need any kind of async signaling, instead the node.js app collects and caches all incoming data, and when the other application polls for data you transmit all the data that has arrived since last poll.

There are many other ways to do it as well, just read the article I linked to in my comment to learn more about all of them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out that there multiple ways of inter-process communication for e.g. message passing, shared memory , files etc.
Here i would like to recommend a reactive approach to solve this issue since as you mentioned the data can be transferred asynchronously.
You can use an in-memory datasource such as [redis](http://redis.io/) to read and write data to it. It should provide a nice integration with node js being a no sql database. This will help you to reduce latency of file I/O. Now you can build a publisher/subscriber paradigm where the subscribers get notified about any changes in the DB. Redis provides an [interface](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) for the same. Let me know if there are doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Use sockets with localhost, I think is good.